# How to find matched sub-sub documents and select some of sub document property in feathers js / mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm using feathersjs and feathers-mongoose and I'm trying to find sub-sub documents within given date. How can I find these using feathersjs query or mongoose query.

User Schema is as follow:

```
const users = new mongooseClient.Schema({
        ... ,
        ... ,
        records: [
            {
                plans: [
                    { ... }
                ],
                subtotal: {type: Number, min: [0, 'must be a positive amount'], default: 0.0},
                discount: {type: Number, min: [0, 'must be a positive amount'], default: 0.0},
                total: {type: Number, min: [0, 'must be a positive amount'], default: 0.0},
                paid: {type: Number, min: [0, 'must be a positive amount'], default: 0.0},
                dues: {type: Number, min: [0, 'must be a positive amount'], default: 0.0},
                visits: [
                    {
                        date: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
                        description: {type: String, default: ''},
                        payment: {type: Number, min: [0, 'must be a positive amount'], default: 0.0},
                        comment: {type: String, default: ''},
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I've following entries in my db:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5aeb7ff33729a513c45f0486",
            ... ,
            "records": [
                {
                    "subtotal": 1800,
                    "discount": 0,
                    "total": 1800,
                    "paid": 1800,
                    "dues": 0,
                    "_id": "5b11c14b52965c1d1cf71ecb",
                    "plans": [],
                    "visits": [
                        {
                            "date": "2018-07-16T18:00:00.000Z",
                            "description": "",
                            "payment": 1800,
                            "comment": "",
                            "_id": "5b4e0d737225ad070488ed6e"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "subtotal": 300,
                    "discount": 0,
                    "total": 300,
                    "paid": 300,
                    "dues": 0,
                    "_id": "5b4e0d3f7225ad070488ed6a",
                    "plans": [],
                    "visits": [
                        {
                            "date": "2018-07-17T15:37:35.625Z",
                            "description": "",
                            "payment": 300,
                            "comment": "",
                            "_id": "5b4e0d3f7225ad070488ed6d"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5b54e7470d707a247cee0421",
            "records": [
                {
                    "subtotal": 300,
                    "discount": 0,
                    "total": 300,
                    "paid": 300,
                    "dues": 0,
                    "_id": "5b54e77d0d707a247cee0422",
                    "plans": [],
                    "visits": [
                        {
                            "date": "2018-07-22T20:22:21.830Z",
                            "description": "",
                            "payment": 300,
                            "comment": "",
                            "_id": "5b54e77d0d707a247cee0425"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to get only those visits which are greater than `2018-07-17T15:37:35`

I've used feathers find method which returns all `visits` subdocuments if anyone of it is matched. feathersjs custom service implementation is as follows:

```
async find(params) {
        return this.service.find({
            query: {
                'records.visits.date': {
                    $gte: '2018-07-17T15:37:35'
                },
                $select: ['records._id', 'records.visits']
            }
        });

    }
```

I've used mongoose find method. It returns only matched vistis but return other properties of `records`. mongoose find implementation is as follows:

```
async find(params) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.model.find({
                "records.visits.date": {
                    $gte: '2018-07-17T15:37:35'
                }
            }, {
                'records.visits.$': 1
            }).select('records.visits'))
    }
```

How do i get the following expected result either using feathersjs or mongoose find method? Thanks in advance.

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5aeb7ff33729a513c45f0486",
            "records": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b4e0d3f7225ad070488ed6a",
                    "visits": [
                        {
                            "date": "2018-07-17T15:37:35.625Z",
                            "description": "",
                            "payment": 300,
                            "comment": "",
                            "_id": "5b4e0d3f7225ad070488ed6d"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5b54e7470d707a247cee0421",
            "records": [
                {
                    "_id": "5b54e77d0d707a247cee0422",
                    "visits": [
                        {
                            "date": "2018-07-22T20:22:21.830Z",
                            "description": "",
                            "payment": 300,
                            "comment": "",
                            "_id": "5b54e77d0d707a247cee0425"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```